# Deleting Large data without transaction logs in SQL azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to delete a large amount of data from azure SQL table frequently using the below code, but when deleting records then transactions logs will be created which will consume Database data storage ,how could we perform deletion without transactions logs and consuming database data storage ?

```
                  Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    long maxId = crumbManager.GetMaxId(fromDate,tenantId);
                    var startingTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && maxId > 0 && startingTime.AddHours(2) > DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var query = $@"delete top(10000)  from Crumbs  where CrumbId <= @maxId and TenantId =@tenantId ";
                            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                                {
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxId", maxId);                                       
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tenantId", tenantId);
                                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 200;
                                    var affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    if (affected == 0)
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken.Token);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Databases make changes using a transaction log so that it can handle failures in the middle of a transaction.  So, even delete operations use space in the transaction log.  Now, the transaction log only takes space (when using full recovery like SQL Azure does for user databases) until the next backup operation.  Those are happening every few minutes today, so the time in which space is required on disk for the log is minimal.

There are some operations which are minimally logged and use less space than doing row-by-row deletes.  For example, if you do a truncate table or swap out a partition from a partitioned table (and then drop it), then you generate much less log than doing row-by-row.  You would need to consider some design changes to your schema to enable this pattern since you aren't just deleting all rows now.

Ultimately, you should just focus on making sure that the operation you perform in SQL Azure is efficient.  if you loop over a heap and delete K rows over and over, that can algorithmically perform many scans over the table instead of range scans.  If you do that even without any of the fancy truncate/partition approaches, you may be able to improve the performance of the system over what you might have now.

Hope that helps explain how SQL works a bit.

Comment: Hi ,Is there any option to disable transaction log in azure sql

Comment: as I said, no.  That's not how SQL Server (and thus SQL Azure) works.

Comment: "if you loop over a heap and delete K rows over and over, that can algorithmically perform many scans over the table instead of range scans" - does this mean that bulk deletes (where we can't use `TRUNCATE TABLE`) are best performed using a loop like `WHILE @i < @count BEGIN DELETE FROM [foo] WHERE [pk] < @i; SET @i = @i + 1000 END` ? If so, that feels weird. Why can't we use a single succinct `DELETE FROM` and assume the RDBMS will run it in the most efficient way possible? Are there any `HINT` keywords we can use instead?

Comment: @Dai, the most efficient way to do a large set of deletes (without truncate) is to just do the DELETE command.  However, people often do the N rows at a time approach because they are trying to balance other user requests with cleanup operations on a concurrent system.  So, the smaller delete model is used to have locks held for less time and to block less overall for K concurrent requests.   Also, you would generally just do DELETE TOP (N) without trying to specify the keys so that the optimizer has more choices on how to be efficient in plan selection

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-use-batching-to-improve-performance) techniques to minimize log usage.

```
declare 
       @batch_size int,
       @del_rowcount int = 1

set @batch_size = 100
set nocount on;

while @del_rowcount > 0
       begin
              begin tran
                     delete top (@batch_size)
                     from dbo.LargeDeleteTest

                     set @del_rowcount = @@rowcount

                     print 'Delete row count: ' + cast(@del_rowcount as nvarchar(32))

              commit tran
       end
```

Drop any foreign keys, delete the rows and then recreate the foreign keys can speed up things also.

Comment: The linked article explains how batched operations using TVPs are better than looping a single `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` - but it doesn't mention your technique of running a DML operation on a batched subset of rows. I don't understand how your technique will result in reduced transaction log activity when it necessarily means more operations will be performed compared to a single `DELETE FROM`.

Comment: A delete of millions of records at once may fill up the transaction log and may create a blocking on a whole table. Batching avoids transaction log growth and minimize locking on a table allowing other users to perform DML operations on the table. Compare how the transaction log size has increased after a single DELETE vs deleting on batches, and you will see not only the log increased less but the delete operation finished faster.